# Office 365 API crashing Add-in on Word for Mac

Tags: javascript, safari, office365api, office-js

I have a stable add-in which is now being expanded to run on Apple Macs.

It runs OK, provided you are careful not to drag the display screen wider.
If you do it crashes.

I have now tested on a vanilla jQuery treeview and the same occurs.
Screen scaling seems to "stretch" instead of just moving.
Also tested on a basic html file with enough information to cause scrolling,  likewise crashes when widened. (tested by the scroll bars no longer responding)

**Does anyone have any ideas as to why this fails?**

bug perhaps?

Screen grab of stretched text, and crashed Add-in. (scroll bar ceases to respond)

[image: Stretched text on screen resize]

The code used

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Hello World</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <p>
                    Office 365 API was trying hard here.
                </p>
                <div>
                "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
                </div>
                <div>
                "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Hello Jerry thanks for reporting this. Can you please provide your Word version on Mac?

Comment: Office / Microsoft Word for Mac Version 15.27 (161010)

Comment: thanks please check out my answer below, an OS update will fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jerry - Upon further investigation we were able to repro this issue. We were able to repro it on OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

However, on updated OS X 10.11 or 10.12 ( El Capitan  or Sierra, respectively) the issue does not repro any more.  So I recommend you to upgrade your OS X to either of those versions. We are also going to fix the issue for Yosemite, but it might take a while for the fix to see the light.

Please give it a try and let us know the outcomes.

Thanks!